# Overflow hidden for an "a" tag inside an absolute positioned div with border-radius

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position, absolute

I am trying to enclose the a tag inside an absolute positioned div with border-radius 100%. Actually I want to disable the ability to click the link, outside of the circular parent div. But I can't make it... I was with the impression that I could do this with overflow hidden, but still I can click the link from the outside of the "circle".

Any ideas?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <a id="logo-link" class="logo-link" href="#" title="WEBSITE">
      <img src="logo-sq.png" alt="LOGO">
      <div class="logo-text">
        <span class="site-title">SITE</span>
        <span class="slogan">SLOGAN</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  position:relative;
}
.logo {
    right: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 4px dotted #022f66;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.logo-link {
    width: auto;
    height:300px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/joomquery/7hwq5xc3/

Comment: Why are you nesting the link (`.logo-link`) into a wrapper (`.logo`)?

Comment: @ihmels thanks for taking the time to comment - I ended up without the outer div - but yet if the inner elements (think the logo img) is exceeding the circle, still the link is accessible from the outside of the circle. Likely overflow won't work on this case if the outer element is positioned as absolute or something like that... I have to enforce the inner image's corners to stay inside the circle.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it seems that only WebKit/Blink based browsers have this problem.

Comment: I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44700902/3527303). This solution also works in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the border radius on the anchor and the overflow hidden it will work

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
}
.logo {
    right: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 4px dotted #022f66;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.logo-link {
    width: auto;
    height:300px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <a id="logo-link" class="logo-link" href="#" title="WEBSITE">
      <img src="logo-sq.png" alt="LOGO">
      <div class="logo-text">
        <span class="site-title">SITE</span>
        <span class="slogan">SLOGAN</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was going to post same answer, but I really have no idea why adding `border radius and overflow hidden` on anchor tag is working but not on it's parent. Can you explain?

Comment: Thanks Musa, this is something I have tried - still it doesn't work... run your snippet and put the mouse over the top  left corner of the circle, on the outside... the link is still clickable...

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I don't actually know, I guess its because of the absolute positioning of the div

Comment: @Sbpro I guess its browser dependent or something because it works for me on latest chrome.

Comment: hmm, on SO and jsfiddle I am using Safari and your snippet didn't work - with Chrome your snippet works - but still on the actual html page it doesn't ( i already work with Chrome there)... anyhow thanks for helping.

Comment: @Musa: I ended up removing the outer div and only using the a tag - but yet if the inner elements (think the logo img) is exceeding the circle, still the link is accessible from the outside of the circle. I have to enforce the inner image's corners to stay inside the circle. Likely overflow won't work on this case if the outer element is positioned as absolute or something like that... So maybe someone could give us an answer about how this is supposed to be working...

Answer (score 0):

I would apply the style directly to the `a` element and then wrap around a `div` element as a workaround. I tested it in Firefox (54) and Chromium (58).

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 20px;
}

.logo a {
  border: 1px solid #022f66;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.logo a::before {
  background: #fff;
  border: 4px dotted #022f66;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: -6px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000;
  content: " ";
  left: -6px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -6px;
  top: -6px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <a id="logo-link" class="logo-link" href="#" title="WEBSITE">
      <img src="logo-sq.png" alt="LOGO">
      <div class="logo-text">
        <span class="site-title">SITE</span>
        <span class="slogan">SLOGAN</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```